# How does Mahout store users Preferences to allow fast similarity computation and how does it work?

Tags: java, data-structures, machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine

I'm coding a small Recommendation system for a school project where i'm supposed to look for similarity between items according to users behavior. I've already tried Mahout, and what's really impressive is the way it's able to compute similarity between two users or items extremely fast even on very large dataSets. I searched over the Mahout in Action book without finding an exact answer. The authors exhibit the names of the classes used and not the mechanisms. So, I tried following the same data representation, but when it comes to calculating the similarity between two items, it's very time consuming. I have two `int` arrays of preferences for each user, and two other score arrays for scores.

I used hashing to determine the intersection between the `userPreference` array and compute an Euclidean Similarity fast as shown in the code below, but without any success. I need Help please :(

```
Item item1 = (dataModel).getItem(item1_ID);
Item item2 = (dataModel).getItem(item2_ID);
int[] i1_users = item1.getUsersId();
int[] i2_users = item2.getUsersId();
float[] i1_scores = item1.getScore();
float[] i2_scores = item2.getScore();
IntFloatOpenHashMap tempHash = new IntFloatOpenHashMap();
for (int i= 0; i < i1_u.length; ++i)
  tempHash.put(i1_users[i], i1_scores[i]);

  for (int i = 0; i < i2_users.length; i++)
  {
    if (tempHash.containsKey(i2_users[i])) {
      diff = tempHash.get(i2_users[i]) - i2_scores[i];
      dist += diff * diff;
    }
  }
 // return Math.sqrt(dist);
```

Comment: What dimensionality does your problem have? I also guess that it is sparse, so you are doing a lot of useless iterations and lookups.

Comment: The dimension is around 60000, yes the data is sparse, so i did store the users having already given a preference for item1 or item2 respectively in i1_users and i2_users (and so for their corresponding scores), but it's slow :(

Comment: Which version of Apache Mahout are you working on ? Do you want to do similarity computation In-Memory or over a cluster of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what you are trying to calculate ( Item Similarity or User Similarity ) based on preference values, you can improve the speed of your code. You code has O(N^2) time complexity, but Mahout does it in O(N).

You can check the implementation:

- `userSimilarity` -- https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/mahout-0.9/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/AbstractSimilarity.java#L110
- `itemSimilarity` -- https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/mahout-0.9/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/AbstractSimilarity.java#L225

Basically you can iterate the two user id arrays in parallel, and also you can avoid creating `tempHash`. You gain both in terms of space and time. I hope that helps.

Comment: ah thanks, so i assume that usersId arrays are sorted at model fetching time, i'll give it a shot, and is it possible to accelerate the computations even faster using a multi-threaded approach ? (sorry, for instance i don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up, once i get 15 i'll remember to do it :)